# Anonymous Down-Vote Compensation Program

Tags: discussion

Friends of EE.SE, We have a problem. *Someone* keeps randomly down-voting the answers of our high reputation users without giving any explanation, and this is causing quite a stir.

To alleviate this issue, I am offering the **Anonymous Down-Vote Compensation Program** to help ease the minds of those affected by random anonymous down-votes. Applying for down-vote relief is **easy**! Simply create an answer to this question with a link to your answer that has a down-vote. I will be notified of your answer, and will then give you an up-vote to compensate your vote total, no questions asked.

Please note that down-votes are very easy to cast. Over 1000 users on EE.SE can currently cast a down-vote without any additional provocation. Down-votes can even be cast accidentally through fat-fingering the mobile interface! While you may be tempted to treat an anonymous "This answer is not helpful" down-vote like professional design review criticism from a 5-member panel filled with Ph.Ds each with 40 years experience in the field; *Please Stay Calm! Help is on the way!* While I monitor my inbox regularly, I cannot guarantee 24/7 support. If you are interested in upgrading this service to a *Platinum 24/7 Service*, you may contribute $50 USD to my [PayPal account](https://www.paypal.com/xclick/business=childsplaycharity@childsplaycharity.org&item_name=Childs+Play+Charity&no_note=1&tax=0&currency_code=USD).

**F.A.Q.:**

- **Q:** Will this erase my downvote? **A:** Sadly even the **Anonymous Down-Vote Compensation Program** is unable to eliminate the sting of the -1. However, your net reputation will be +8, and your answer score won't sink any lower.
- **Q:** What happens if you (@W5VO) already up-voted my answer? **A:** Don't you worry about that! I personally guarantee that you will get one more up-vote than you normally would get. If I can't increase your total, then I'll get someone who can!
- **Q:** Who is eligible for this program? **A:** This is a program for high reputation users. Specifically, that is any user with a reputation over 20,000. If you don't have that much reputation, there's probably just something wrong with your answer anyways.
- **Q:** Why are anonymous downvotes even allowed? **A:** To prevent the inevitable witchhunt that happens every time someone feels wrongly targeted by a down-vote.

*Enjoy!
-W5VO*

Comment: Your ADVC Program seems only to apply to answers and not questions. I have taken the liberty of entering this question into my own ADVCP (for questions only).  *Some people here have no sense of humour :(*

Comment: @MikeJ-UK I would gladly offer this service for questions, but eligible users rarely ask questions (and Meta doesn't count). Any contributions to refill the vote pool are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I, for one, welcome our new anonymous-downvote-compensating overlords.

Comment: This assumes that high reputation users post everything perfectly 100% of the time? Half of them aren't even sane.

Comment: @KennyRobinson Surely you jest! We have placed these people at the top of our community for a reason - they are never wrong! Each of them has decades of experience, and they KNOW that a single downvote could jeopardize their career and reputation. THAT is why I pledge to work quickly and efficiently to do as much as I can to right the wrongs against them!

Comment: For those that do not realize this, this post is tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: Does your program apply to other SE sites too?

Comment: @jippie Unfortunately, this is only for EE.SE for a few reasons: I am not well practiced in other fields, I have not been a member of the other sites for very long, and it would be difficult to judge what an appropriate reputation threshold for participants. The final reason is probably the primary reason - it takes 1,000 rep to see up/down vote totals.

Comment: @W5VO are you saying you don't trust me (or rather 10k+ members) when they say they were downvoted in anther stack!?

Comment: Funny how often it's those with the most rep points to spare who get the most riled about this sort of thing. These are highly tuned, sensitive experts, and I am glad to see that they can now get some reassurance for their bruised egos! Good on you! =P

Comment: @W5VO - This gives me something to strive for! When I become eligible, not only will I have the reputation to do unto many what they can not do to me, but I'll have immunity too! Brilliant. The platinum service sounds too good to be true ;-) Irony is alive, and useful to make more than magnety things B-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while presumably a joke it might lead some users to think that asking for vote compensation is acceptable rather than reporting questionable voting privately.

Comment: @W5VO Rather than closing it as PeterJ suggested, can I edit your question to add the [fun](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29323871#29323871) tag? Or will it upset you?